# Apache Superset - Issue visualizing data with deck.gl geojson

Tags: geojson, apache-superset, deck.gl

Trying to visualize data into a deck.gl geojson but nothing seem to be working.

Here is the BigQuery SQL query.

`select ST_ASGEOJSON(ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-73.96943,40.78519],[-73.96082,40.78095]],[[-73.96415,40.79229],[-73.95544,40.78854]],[[-73.97162,40.78205],[-73.96374,40.77715]],[[-73.9788,40.77247],[-73.97036,40.76811]]]}')) as geo`

This should give us four lines in Central Park NY.

I have tested the GeoJSON with [geojson.io](https://geojson.io) and it seems to be valid.

**Valid GeoJSON**

[image: Valid GeoJSON]

When trying to visualize that into a deck.gl Geojson chart nothing seems to show.

**deck.gl geojson result in Apache Superset**

[image: deck.gl geojson result in Apache Superset]

Could someone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "deck.gl Path" example called "Path", which seems like a better fit in your case. You will see that the JSON column should essentially just contain a `LineString`'s "coordinates" array (i.e. of <longitude, latitude> position arrays):

[image]

In your case, you would break your `MutltiLineString` into four individual `LineString`s, putting each one's "coordinates" array into it's own row in your dataset.